# Comparing Arrays in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I am learning kotlin at the moment. Is there a way to "compare" two arrays? For example
I have an array (1,2,3) and an array (1,2,1). The output should be something like this: 
"2,2" for "took two from the indice two".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems a strange (I mean, not so "common") feature, you may need to implement this function yourself. What is the output for input (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 3)? What is the output for (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7)? What is the output for input (1, 2, 3), (3, 2, 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) as follows:

```
val array1 = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val array2 = listOf(1, 2, 1)

val out1 = array1.zip(array2, Int::minus)

println(out1) // [0, 0, 2]
```

This gives you a new array with the values of the differences.

From there, it's just a short step to the (uncommon) format you're requesting using [`mapIndexedNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-indexed-not-null.html):

```
val out2 = out1.mapIndexedNotNull{ i, v -> if (v != 0) listOf(i, v) else null }

println(out2) // [[2, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works so far but is there a way to access the numbers of out2?

Comment: `out2[0][0]` and `out2[0][1]`